# Slow down UIScrollView / Cap the max speed

Tags: ios, performance, uiscrollview, cap

I have a pagingEnabled scrollview which dynamnically adds more content as the user approaches the very end of it. Paging enabled allows me to force the user to be only able to scroll one item at a time.

The problem is that adding additional content takes time. If the user scrolls through my content too quickly (you can still go pretty darn quickly even with pagingEnabled = TRUE), the scroll attempts will cause my scrollview to occasionally "bounce" as though it hit the end. If the user attempts to scroll again, immediately afterwards, they can continue scrolling. I wish to prevent this bounce from happening in a user-friendly way.

I assume this bounce is happening because the iPod/iPhone cannot load the scrollview content in time. It is actually a fairly resource intensive process, I'd imagine (Each subView added to the scrollview is a UIImageView with a UITextView subview added to it).

I need a way to cap the scrollview's speed. I tried playing with decelerate rate but I didn't notice any difference. What can I do?

Comment: I couldn't cap the max speed. The user is all powerful. Ended up just living with the potential bounces happening. Although, I did create a spinner bubble at the end of my bubbles which would load with content once my server requests for additional data came back! :)